# When using @response and @request for json, I meet with some problems

Tags: ajax, json, spring, model-view-controller

LoginController.java:

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value="receive", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public  RegInfo receiveData(@RequestBody RegInfo info){//

        System.out.println("come here");
        System.out.println(info.getRealname());
        return info;
    }
}
```

register.xml:

```
    $("#sub").click(function(){
    var m = {
            "realname": $("#real_name").val(),
            "phonenumber": $("#phone_number").val()             
        };
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/demo/user/receive",
        data:m,

        dataType:"json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            alert("nihao");
        },
        erroe:function(data){
            alert("保存失败 ")
        }
    })
});
```

RegInfo.java:

```
public class RegInfo {

    private String realname;

    private String phonenumber;

    //private boolean sex;

    public RegInfo(){

    }

    public void setRealname(String realname){
        this.realname= realname;
    }
    public String getRealname(){
        return realname;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber){
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }
    public String getPhonenumber(){
        return phonenumber;
    }
```

demo-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.lhao.core"/>

<!-- 默认的注解映射的支持 -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

I have imported jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar, jackson-core-2.1.4.jar, jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar in the lib but I cannot see the print in the console and it shows "400 bad request" in Chrome. I have tried some ways but it does no effect.

Comment: `400 Bad Request` usually shows up when Spring/jackson can't deserialize your request to the given type. Your model looks okay to me, so I'd first try removing the `consumes` parameter to your `@RequestMapping` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your javascript variable to json before sending the request to server. JSON.stringify() does the conversion. Based on the code given above, this should solve the issue. well hopefully.

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    var m = {
            "realname": $("#real_name").val(),
            "phonenumber": $("#phone_number").val()             
        };
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/demo/user/receive",
        data:JSON.stringify(m),

        dataType:"json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            alert("nihao");
        },
        erroe:function(data){
            alert("保存失败 ")
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: thank you.I have resolved this problem.first i have tried JSON.stringify(m) but it does no effect.then i replace jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar.. with jackson-core-asl.jar and jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar ,it does effect.